# Why C is best for OS programming?

Tags: c

I am a computer  science student and I am trying to follow Operating System Module. Still I am confused about which language should I use for testing, C or C++. Most people say C is good.Why c is important for operating systems??

Comment: Erm, who said C is best for OS programming? Depends on the hardware, on what the OS is designed to accomplish, etc.

Comment: I would go for assembly... or better yet, byte code ;-) Mov ax,ah

Comment: But still most of OS are written in C right?(I know that there are various OS which are coded using Assembly)

Comment: One thing many OS programmers want is, the language does not do hard-to-predict stuff behind their backs. Most C++ features are precisely doing stuff behind programmers back: templates, virtual methods and overriding, all overloading, exceptions transferring control flow...

Comment: Go to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ to discuss this topic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C is used for operating systems for four major reasons:

1. It is a low level portable representation of programs executable on Von Neumann machines (the vast majority of modern machines). With small, vendor-specific modifications, it can be used for non-Von Neumann machines. (Usually the only major omission for such machines is function pointers)
2. It was used for Unix. Most modern operating systems (that is, Windows NT, OSX, Linux, BSD, etc.) are Unix clones of some sort.
3. The POSIX standards are specified in terms of it.
4. It doesn't require extensive runtime support.

Comment: ...with extensions to support modified Harvard and straight Harvard architectures. (Many PICs and other embedded processors fall into this category).

Comment: @nneonneo: You can work with those architectures with modified C, yes. But then it isn't C anymore.

Comment: The modifications are usually quite minor, and some may touch only the linker. (It usually just boils down to some extra type attributes, but the code is otherwise plain C).

Comment: @nneonneo: Perhaps the modifications are minor. But they aren't standardized. One vendor probably has completely different annotations from another. C is very rigidly defined in ANSI ISO IEC 9899; the extensions to support Harvard architectures aren't there.